# My battery died toward the end of Yosemite installation. Now login screen freezes

Tags: macos, applecare

My Yosemite installation was at "less than a minute remaining" for about 5 mins. Then my battery died. When I charged and turned on the power, I got to the Yosemite login screen. When I log in, the password succeeds, then the login screen reappears but the screen freezes.

I've tried it about 20 times now. Same thing happens every time.

Comment: reinstall Yosemite, this time with power cable plugged in.

Comment: How? I can't get past the login screen.

Answer (score 2):

Access OS X Recovery by holding <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> from the time you boot your system until you see the Apple logo. [Further instructions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718):

> After your computer finishes starting up, you should see a desktop with an OS X menu bar and an OS X Utilities window with the options listed above.
>
> In order to reinstall OS X, you need to be connected to the Internet using Ethernet or Wi-Fi. If you're using a wireless Internet connection, click the Wi-Fi menu in the upper-right corner of the screen to select a nearby Wi-Fi network. Choose your preferred network name and enter a username and password to join the network if needed.